# Get rendered HTML using SSR in nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use SSR with next.js, but when I use `getServerSideProps`, it shows up in the network logs as a JSON and also the rendered HTML contains this JSON.
Is there a way to avoid this and do the complete rendering on server side and just get the rendered HTML on client side? Any help will be much appreciated.